# AVR-GCC - enum error with included header

Tags: c, gcc, enums, avr

I am having trouble spotting where I am making a mistake and not sure how to google the solution. I am getting the following error:

```
In file included from buttons.h:8,
                 from buttons.c:1:
debug_mode.h:14: error: expected ')' before 'Button'
```

I have an enum declared in buttons.h

```
#ifndef BUTTONS_HEADER
#define BUTTONS_HEADER

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include "uart.h"
#include "debug_mode.h"

typedef enum {
    NO_BUTTON,
    BUTTON1,
    BUTTON2,
    BUTTON3,
    BUTTON4,
    BUTTON5,
    BUTTON6
}
ButtonFlags;

void CheckButtons();
void SetButtonFlag();
void ProcessButtons();

#endif
```

I am including it in another header debug_mode.h:

```
#ifndef DEBUG_MODE_HEADER
#define DEBUG_MODE_HEADER

#include "uart.h"
#include <stdbool.h> 
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include "buttons.h"

bool DebugModeEnabled = false;

void SetDebugMode();
void AnnounceDebugMode(bool State);
void DebugAnnounceLEDState();
void DebugAnnounceButtonState(ButtonFlags Button);

#endif
```

and the debug_mode.c:

```
#include "debug_mode.h"

void DebugAnnounceButtonState(ButtonFlags Button)
{
    SendUARTString_P(DEBUGMODE_BUTTON_PRESSED_MSG);
    switch (Button)
    {
        case 1: SendUARTString_P(DEBUGMODE_BUTTON1_MSG); break;
        default: break;
    }
}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: I spot an include cycle. You're including buttons.h which includes debug_mode.h, which includes button.h...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your headers buttons.h and debug_mode.h are including each other. You will need to refactor your code in such a way to remove this circular dependency.

Comment: Thanks refactored. Knew about circular dependancies, but for some reason didn't think it may have been the culprit.